Conjugate of a Gel'fand pattern
Background:
A Gel'fand pattern is a set of numbers
$$
\left[\begin{array}{}
\lambda_{1,n} &      & \lambda_{2,n} &        &        & \dots  &        & &  \lambda_{n-1,n} &             & \lambda_{n,n} \\
             & \lambda_{1,n-1} &   & \lambda_{2,n-1} &        &    \dots     & &  \lambda_{n-2,n-1} &           & \lambda_{n-1,n-1} \\
             &      &        &     &        & \dots  \\
             &      &        &     & \lambda_{1,2} &  & \lambda_{2,2} \\   
             &      &        &     &        & \lambda_{1,1}
\end{array}\right]
$$
which satisfy the "betweenness condition" $\lambda_{i,j+1} \geq \lambda_{i+j,j+1} \geq \lambda_{ij}$, i.e., that each number has to be (weakly) between the two numbers above it.
Gel'fand patterns can be put into a one-to-one correspondence with Young tableaux, where each row corresponds to the shape of the Young diagram for the first $j$ particles. For example:
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 5 \\
3 &   &   \\
4
\end{matrix}
&\longleftrightarrow&
\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
& 2 && 1 && 1 && 0 &  \\
&& 2 && 1 && 0 &&     \\
&&& 2 && 0 &&&        \\
&&&& 1 &&&&           \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & \\
2 & 5 & \\
4 &   &
\end{matrix}
&\longleftrightarrow&
\begin{bmatrix}
2 && 2 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
& 2 && 1 && 1 && 0 &  \\
&& 2 && 1 && 0 &&     \\
&&& 1 && 1 &&&        \\
&&&& 1 &&&&           \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
Question:
Is there a closed-form way of finding the "conjugate" of a Gel'fand pattern? That is, knowing the $\lambda_{i,j}$, can I calculate $\tilde{\lambda}_{ij}$? For Young tableaux, one can obtain the conjugate by reflecting across the diagonal. The conjugates for the examples would be
$$
\begin{align}
\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & 4 \\
2 &   &   \\
5
\end{matrix}
&\longleftrightarrow&
\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
& 3 && 1 && 0 && 0 &  \\
&& 2 && 1 && 0 &&     \\
&&& 1 && 1 &&&        \\
&&&& 1 &&&&           \\
\end{bmatrix}
\\
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 4 \\
3 & 5
\end{matrix}
&\longleftrightarrow&
\begin{bmatrix}
3 && 2 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\
& 3 && 1 && 0 && 0 &  \\
&& 2 && 1 && 0 &&     \\
&&& 2 && 0 &&&        \\
&&&& 1 &&&&           \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
